# Facebook Graph API Query Using "With"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

Using the Facebook Graph API Explorer (v2.4) I retrieve the feed of a page I manage using 1478743469096769/feed/ .  The Explorer offers fields that can be added to the query, "with=" and "q=".

How are these fields used in constructing a query?

I know how q= is used here:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=twilight&type=page

However, something like this gives an error:
1478743469096769/feed/?q=Nipped

Given the unqualified data set provided below, what are examples of functional queries using the "with=" & "q= fields" that result in a subset of data being returned?

1478743469096769/feed/?with=

1478743469096769/feed/?q=

Finally, are these fields documented in Graph API reference?  I am unable to locate any such documentation.

```html
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "I got my little baby peppers to like water, we had a little water play today!",
      "created_time": "2015-10-03T21:32:22+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_433449873505285"
    },
    {
      "message": "LOL!!!!!
#CATSALLDAY #Cats",
      "story": "Cat Nipped shared CATS All Day, Every Day Purrrrfect's photo.",
      "created_time": "2015-10-03T15:43:40+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483703968600719"
    },
    {
      "message": "Do you think he will jump?",
      "created_time": "2015-10-03T11:11:26+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483653421939107"
    },
    {
      "message": "What is he asking to play with?",
      "created_time": "2015-10-03T00:35:25+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483563051948144"
    },
    {
      "message": "Always!!
#CATSALLDAY #Cats",
      "story": "Cat Nipped shared CATS All Day, Every Day Purrrrfect's photo.",
      "created_time": "2015-10-02T16:48:52+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483497678621348"
    },
    {
      "message": "I have liked and shared your page.  I hope a lucky kitty gets you soon!",
      "created_time": "2015-10-02T14:35:31+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483475311956918"
    },
    {
      "message": "Could you get dressed for work with this in the way?",
      "created_time": "2015-10-02T11:11:23+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483436231960826"
    },
    {
      "message": "Do you think she is a cat or cheetah?",
      "created_time": "2015-10-02T00:37:25+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483345085303274"
    },
    {
      "message": "Lol!!!!! Mommy appreciates the horrifying present. 
#CATSALLDAY #Cats",
      "story": "Cat Nipped shared CATS All Day, Every Day Purrrrfect's photo.",
      "created_time": "2015-10-01T16:02:49+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483277925309990"
    },
    {
      "message": "If it's anything I LOVE, it's a pwecious li'l kitty!",
      "created_time": "2015-10-01T14:26:44+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483262585311524"
    },
    {
      "message": "Are those eyebrows real or drawn on?",
      "created_time": "2015-10-01T11:12:13+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483220735315709"
    },
    {
      "message": "How many minutes do you think he would allow you to rub that tummy?",
      "created_time": "2015-10-01T00:42:11+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483115081992941"
    },
    {
      "message": "Good Luck getting your new Furr-ever companion!!!",
      "created_time": "2015-09-30T16:29:16+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1483024235335359"
    },
    {
      "message": "What is your cat's name?

This contest is inspired by Kelly's cat Peppers.  (That name is just so great. :) )  The prize is a really nice quality necklace. (includes mailing to any US address)

To enter:
1) Like this post
2) Leave a comment with your cat's name.

One winner will be picked from all comments in about 3 days.

Have fun!

THIS PROMOTION IS IN NO WAY SPONSORED, ENDORSED OR ADMINISTERED BY, OR ASSOCIATED WITH, FACEBOOK. ANY QUESTIONS, COMMENTS OR COMPLAINTS REGARDING THE PROMOTION WILL BE DIRECTED TO SPONSOR, NOT FACEBOOK. NO PURCHASE IS NECESSARY TO ENTER OR WIN. A PURCHASE WILL NOT INCREASE YOUR CHANCES OF WINNING. ALL FEDERAL, STATE, LOCAL, AND MUNICIPAL LAWS AND REGULATIONS APPLY. VOID WHERE PROHIBITED. ALL PARTICIPANTS AGREE TO RELEASE FACEBOOK FROM ANY AND ALL OBLIGATION AND LIABILITY ASSOCIATED WITH THIS PROMOTION.

Official Rules: https://www.facebook.com/CatNipped/posts/1481914152113034",
      "created_time": "2015-09-28T23:18:32+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1482648088706307"
    },
    {
      "message": "Peppers!  I love it - what a great name! Thank you so much Kelly.",
      "story": "Cat Nipped shared Kelly Altizer's photo.",
      "created_time": "2015-09-28T20:43:27+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1482630482041401"
    },
    {
      "message": "This is my baby peppers, i got him when he was 1 years old, i took him in because his previous owner, did not like him so he beat him. I couldnt stand by while this little guy was being hurt. He is now my little boy, oh and he is 3 years old now.",
      "created_time": "2015-09-28T18:33:39+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_432287186954887"
    },
    {
      "message": "cats lower blood pressure, love unconditionally, help cheer their human up when sad <3 there's a few tidbits to share with your dad, dads usually love that kinda stuff, lol",
      "created_time": "2015-09-28T07:35:42+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1482514855386297"
    },
    {
      "message": "Thankyou for the like to your page !",
      "created_time": "2015-09-27T21:52:02+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1482441195393663"
    },
    {
      "message": "Thanks Liz for letting Devin post your awesome pic!",
      "story": "Cat Nipped shared Devin Hales's photo.",
      "created_time": "2015-09-27T21:24:32+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1482438852060564"
    },
    {
      "message": "This is my cat Liz. She will be 5 years old in October. I got her from the Humane  Society when she was 8 weeks old. I hope you get your kitten soon. :]",
      "created_time": "2015-09-27T01:17:21+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1646543262291309"
    },
    {
      "message": "Thanks for the post Kim. Cute Cat! What's it's name?",
      "story": "Cat Nipped shared Kim Marie Bonafilia's photo.",
      "created_time": "2015-09-26T21:27:01+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1482190908752025"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2015-09-26T21:07:04+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_994359590584809"
    },
    {
      "message": "What do you think this kitty is thinking about? 

I'm going to give this new bracelet away to one person who comments. (free and I even pay shipping) 

Have fun and participate, just answer by commenting.

I will pick a winner from my favorite comments in about 3 days.

THIS PROMOTION IS IN NO WAY SPONSORED, ENDORSED OR ADMINISTERED BY, OR ASSOCIATED WITH, FACEBOOK. ANY QUESTIONS, COMMENTS OR COMPLAINTS REGARDING THE PROMOTION WILL BE DIRECTED TO SPONSOR, NOT FACEBOOK. NO PURCHASE IS NECESSARY TO ENTER OR WIN. A PURCHASE WILL NOT INCREASE YOUR CHANCES OF WINNING. ALL FEDERAL, STATE, LOCAL, AND MUNICIPAL LAWS AND REGULATIONS APPLY. VOID WHERE PROHIBITED. ALL PARTICIPANTS AGREE TO RELEASE FACEBOOK FROM ANY AND ALL OBLIGATION AND LIABILITY ASSOCIATED WITH THIS PROMOTION.

Official Rules: https://www.facebook.com/CatNipped/posts/1481914152113034",
      "created_time": "2015-09-26T20:48:24+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1482186108752505"
    },
    {
      "message": "Get this person their kitty dad! #Catman",
      "created_time": "2015-09-26T01:04:27+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1481994045438378"
    },
    {
      "message": "Help prove to my dad how much I want a cat, just click Like Page. If I get enough, I get my very 1st Kitty.",
      "created_time": "2015-09-25T21:10:33+0000",
      "id": "1478743469096769_1481959528775163"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/1478743469096769/feed?format=json&since=1443907942&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAABjtzZCw31guzYlUrCdrm1fhp3IAFoSSlJ3SyNteXXSL0sHHRIyLyQe1Os7jG9lvqpoMWVOiIrZAR2ri21Ir6RFNUaqRFIZBcWubjSNOGubqCTvcoQ6RJSS3jhS69kCJNnnbZAaulbTi09XWZAQGrL2xxG9wkTIJk0Na8FpMvE7aifQoOLNknph0B6zoggZDZD&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdAHcJwwpPWePaE3eiGWhpekDnQUPRHzbcZBU9J5BZAAa0ZBWMug5ZBxseMCcLIJjfiFsXSZBH27161cZCrhjPhDAs0lmQSvIJJrILo9ZBnuHakzfvl5AZDZD&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/1478743469096769/feed?format=json&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAABjtzZCw31guzYlUrCdrm1fhp3IAFoSSlJ3SyNteXXSL0sHHRIyLyQe1Os7jG9lvqpoMWVOiIrZAR2ri21Ir6RFNUaqRFIZBcWubjSNOGubqCTvcoQ6RJSS3jhS69kCJNnnbZAaulbTi09XWZAQGrL2xxG9wkTIJk0Na8FpMvE7aifQoOLNknph0B6zoggZDZD&limit=25&until=1443215433&__paging_token=enc_AdAHLzJNolBL0Sdnt4z9rREqmL0YCcT6gxIoeEi0ziZA9XPqgqyH8ckDYm6oqDpqZBjxhSGnmyshSGBZAzGQA3VYekErRWeufTreRx7zZBqdwRvmygZDZD"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not filter the feed using these parameters. The feed endpoints don’t offer any search functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Sure is frustrating that both parameters are offered as pre-defined choices for both feed and posts endpoints.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's not what younexpected, but here is q: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#multirequests